# Native XML WebService With Authentication Basic and SSL

Tags: sql-server-2005, web-services, ssl, basic-authentication

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and the Native XML WebServices. The integrated authentication via HTTP:80 works fine. But i need the basic authentication which requires SSL. So if i change the web service to ssl i always get a connection reset (101). I tried several ports 80,443,9999 with the same outcome. 
What is the error?

```
--EXEC sp_delete_http_namespace_reservation N'https://ATWEZE99103DAT:9999/sql/s047'
EXEC SP_RESERVE_HTTP_NAMESPACE N'https://ATWEZE99103DAT:9999/sql/s047'
go
--drop endpoint S047SSLPOINT;
CREATE ENDPOINT S047SSLPOINT
STATE = Started
AS HTTP
( PATH= '/sql/s047'
, PORTS= (SSL)
, SSL_PORT=9999
, SITE = 'ATWEZE99103DAT'
, AUTHENTICATION= (BASIC)
, COMPRESSION=Enabled
)
FOR SOAP
(
webmethod 'M001_SetSupplies'
 (
    NAME = 'sapio.dbo.USP_SetSupplies'
    , schema = standard
  )
,webmethod 'M002_SetDetailedPlanning'
 (
    NAME = 'sapio.dbo.USP_SetDetailedPlanning'
    , schema = standard)
     , LOGIN_TYPE=MIXED
    , WSDL = DEFAULT
    ,  schema = standard
    , database = 'SAPIO'
    , namespace = 'urn:other'
  )
go
```

Comment: The script above is successful and "HTTP SSL" Service started.
So the tipp there won't help: http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/26/485293.aspx